# How does cross domain file (receiver) work?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, communication, receiver

So, how does it work?  How come having a receiver.html can allow cross domain communication?  I... just... don't understand.

For example, (using Heyzap as example)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://tools.heyzap.com/external/tools/v4.js"></script> <script type="text/javascript">   HeyzapTools.load({
    game_key: "your-game-key-here",
    hz_receiver_url: "http://example.com/hz_receiver.html"  });

</script>
```

and the hz_receiver.html has this content:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <script src="/external/tools/hz_receiver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

so, why it will allow cross domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a day of research, I find out it is a way to deal with cross domain communication.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735305.aspx

probably the js inside the receiver.html has a iframe.. using same concept to deal with the cross domain.